# Storing dictionaries inside a dataframe that have duplicate entries in a unique value column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame with a column including duplicate values due to having data across multiple years which I want to convert into having only unique values. To do this I want to have the other columns converted into dictionaries which would show the data for all the years as key value pairs in the format {'year': value}. This has to be done to all the other columns except the column with unique values.
My input data frame looks like below

[Original input data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORYtx.png)

Reproducible code for the data frame

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': {0: 'a1', 1: 'a2', 2: 'a3', 3: 'a4'}, 
    'Unique': {0: 'b1', 1: 'b1', 2: 'b2', 3: 'b2'}, 
    'Year': {0: 2017, 1: 2008, 2: 2017, 3: 2008} , 
    'C': {0: 'c1', 1: 'c2', 2: 'c3', 3: 'c4'}
})
```

So far I have tried getting the value-year combinations for each variable into lists and adding it to a dictionary in hopes of converting it  back to a data frame. But this won't let me get the same result as expected output.

Sample of what I have done so far is

```py
B_list = list(df["Unique"])
temp_dict = {}
new_dict = {}
for a in set(Unique_list):
    i = 0
    new_dict[a] = {}
    temp_list = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if df["Unique"][i] == a:      
            temp_list.append(str(df["Year"][i]) +": " +  df["A"][i])
            i = i+1
        new_dict[a] = temp_list
```

It gives the output dictionary as

```py
{'b1': ['2017: a1', '2008: a2'], 
 'b2': ['2017: a3', '2008: a4']}
```

which when I turn into a data frame converts as a

[Resulting data frame which is not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoDZ9.png)

While the expected output is a data frame in the format

[Expected output data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvsuA.png)

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots, but paste the dataframes in a code block.

Comment: @RvdBerg It's my first time asking a question. Therefore when I try to embed the daraframe it gives a message saying I need 10 reputations to do so. Kindly tell me if there any other way to do so?

Comment: I do not think you want to work with dictionaries in a dataframe that is kind of an antipattern. I think you want to use a index here.

Comment: Sachi, you're doing allright. Just post the dataframe as its values between "```"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For improve performance if large data better is not use dictionaries in columns, but if small data it is possible by [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with custom function:

```
def f(x):
    y = x.pop('Year')
    c = x.columns.difference(['Unique'])
    return pd.concat([pd.Series([dict(zip(y, x[col]))]).rename(col) for col in c], 1)

df1 = (df.groupby('Unique')
         .apply(f)
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .rename_axis('B')
         .reset_index()
         .sort_index(axis=1))
print (df1)
                          A   B                         C
0  {2017: 'a1', 2008: 'a2'}  b1  {2017: 'c1', 2008: 'c2'}
1  {2017: 'a3', 2008: 'a4'}  b2  {2017: 'c3', 2008: 'c4'}
```

Better solution is create `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Unique','Year']).unstack()
print (df1)
          A         C     
Year   2008 2017 2008 2017
Unique                    
b1       a2   a1   c2   c1
b2       a4   a3   c4   c3
```

Or in index, it depends what need finally:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['Unique','Year'])
print (df2)
              A   C
Unique Year        
b1     2017  a1  c1
       2008  a2  c2
b2     2017  a3  c3
       2008  a4  c4
```

Comment: I understand that this method is not appliable for large scale data. Please advise how to tackle this kind of situation without using dictionaries.

Comment: It worked as expected. Thank you for the suggestions. I think with a bigger dataset a more efficient method like using a multi index as suggested would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionaries in a `pandas` `DataFrame` is kind of an antipattern.

Lets just assume you want your result for each unique `Unique` the values of `A` and `Year`.

We start with your `DataFrame`:

> Just a quick note: you do not have to use the dictionaries for the columns in the DataFrame assignment. You can allready simplify it with lists like so:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'], 
    'Unique': ['b1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b2'], 
    'Year': [2017, 2008, 2017, 2008], 
    'C': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
})
```

Now you can select your data by setting b as an index.

```py
df.set_index('Unique', drop=False, inplace=True)
```

With this you can do:

```
In : df2.loc['b1']                                                           
Out: 
         A Unique  Year   C
Unique                     
b1      a1     b1  2017  c1
b1      a2     b1  2008  c2
```

Comment: I understand that using dictionaries would hinder the performance. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @sachini_rb Its not just about the performance. Using dicts in a dataframe makes it more complex than it needs to be. Using DataFrames as they are intended will help you write your code faster and it makes it more readable for others. Please take some time to read this guide, it will help you: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html .

Answer (score 0):

Try using apply and zip to do that

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'A': {0: 'a1', 1: 'a2', 2: 'a3', 3: 'a4'},
                    'Unique': {0: 'b1', 1: 'b1', 2: 'b2', 3: 'b2'},
                    'Year': {0: 2017, 1: 2008, 2: 2017, 3: 2008} ,
                    'C': {0: 'c1', 1: 'c2', 2: 'c3', 3: 'c4'}})

def converting_into_dict(grp,col_name,key="Year"):
    return dict(zip(grp[key], grp[col_name]))

res = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Unique').apply(lambda x :converting_into_dict(x,"A")),columns=["A"])
res2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Unique').apply(lambda x :converting_into_dict(x,"C")),columns=["B"])
final_res = pd.merge(res,res2,on=['Unique']).reset_index()
print(final_res)
```

```
      Unique         A                         B
0     b1  {2017: 'a1', 2008: 'a2'}  {2017: 'c1', 2008: 'c2'}
1     b2  {2017: 'a3', 2008: 'a4'}  {2017: 'c3', 2008: 'c4'}
```

I hope it would solve your problem